# Excel VBA to Copy and Paste A Changing Value into A Non-Constant Number of Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro to copy the first instance of "8202000-20211902" or similar codes in column N into the same row in column O then into every subsequent row where there exists a ticket number (in the attached screenshot, I'm trying to copy/paste N4 into O4 then O5 and O6).

The difficult thing is regularity. There can exist any number of tickets in column A and the "8202..." value changes with each group of tickets (and not always incrementally, in the screenshot, 20211902 goes to 2021903 but even though the 8202000 part doesn't change, the next code may be 8202000-**20210734** for example)

I'm a total beginner in excel VBA so I don't really know what I'm doing but I've pieced together some code from online sources.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update (6/20):
I have a working solution but I'm sure there's a more elegant solution that 1) limits last row to true last row (around 150) and not a hardcoded row 250
2) does not paste the code in rows where there is no ticket number in column A

`

```
    Sub COPYROWS()
    Dim x As String
    Dim y As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook

    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    Worksheets("123").Activate

    For i = 1 To 200

      If Not Cells(i, 14) = vbNullString And Not Cells(i, 1) = 
      vbNullString Then
        
        x = Cells(i, 14).Value
        
        Cells(i, 15).Select
        
        ActiveCell.Value = x

        
            Do While y <= 2
            
            y = 1
            
            Cells(i, 15).Select
            
            Range(ActiveCell, Cells(250, 15)).Select
            
            Selection.Value = x

            y = y + 1
            
            Exit Do
            Loop
    
      End If
    
    Next i

End Sub
```

`

[SPREADSHEET LAYOUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obiC2.png)

Comment: Using [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/option-explicit-statement) and declaring all your variables should help with the first error

Comment: `loop` needs to be before `next n` for starters.

Comment: ^^^^ Properly indenting your code should help prevent that kind of problem?

Comment: `m` is an integer, but you've got m = some_range. which means you're actully getting `m = some_range.Value`. But we already know the value, you specifically found the next empty cell, so m = 0 every time, guaranteed. I think you meant to do `m = some_range.ROW`

Comment: thanks for all the suggestions so far!